# Retrieving Cells within a WPF DataGrid Column

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I need to get all the cells within a certain column.
there is no property called "Cells" in the GridViewColumn class.

Is there any other way of doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

May I ask you the purpose of getting those cells? And when you say you want a cell, do you want the visual of that cell or the data associated with it?

If it is data, then getting it directly from your ViewModel will be a preferred approach. So if you are following proper MVVM while implementing this, you can have a method in the ViewModel which can easily expose you a specific collection of cell-data corresponds to a column

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://techiethings.blogspot.com/2010/05/get-wpf-datagrid-row-and-cell.html